# Rails - Capistrano - Why the default restart recipe in deploy.rb has "wait: 5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I was wondering why the default `:restart` recipe in the `deploy.rb` file for Capistrano 3 has a `wait: 5` parameter?

Is there a particular reason to wait 5 seconds between each restart?

```
desc 'Restart application'
   task :restart do
     on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
       execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is defined in the [release notes](http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html) of capistrano 3

```
on :all, in: :sequence, wait: 15 do
  # This takes all servers, in sequence and waits 15 seconds between
  # each server, this might be perfect if you are afraid about
  # overloading a shared resource, or want to defer the asset compilation
  # over your cluster owing to worries about load
end
```

Read [more](http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html)